# How to detect post_format in wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I detect what post_format the current post is in the functions in order to fire up specific post scripts?

```
if (has_post_format( 'gallery' )){
    echo 'testing 123';
}
```

I tried that in my functions.php, and on posts that are set to gallery, nothing happens. If I put the echo line outside of the if, it shows up at the top of every page (as expected), why doesn't has_post_format work?

Comment: What does the function `get_post_format()` return?

Comment: As Ares pointed out, it doesn't return anything unless it is inside a loop. Which means I have to find a different way of doing the check. Do you know of any way to run the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has_post_format() will only work inside the loop if you are not providing a POST_ID which is the second argument. If you are not inside the loop you will have to send a post_id.

Since you are doing this from functions.php you need to somehow retrieve the postID. In this case we can do it based on the URL. So,

```
$url = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$postID = url_to_postid($url[0]);
```

now you can do your comparison like this

```
has_post_format('gallery', $postID) { /** do your thing **/ }
```

Comment: I see, is there any way to do this check from outside a loop? As I know you can do  if( ! is_page('x')) to check for a specific page.

Comment: can you give more context on what you are trying to do and where you are running has_post_format()?

Comment: I am loading a specific script that is intended to run only for Gallery type posts. So I thought about wrapping an if = post_format(gallery) statement around the add_action lines in my functions.php

Comment: That does work, but would be bad for resources to have every page load those lines?